# How to use Nullish Coalescing in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

With the release of Typescript 3.7 there is now support for [Nullish Coalescing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing). However it seems like I am using it wrongly.. I have the following structure:

```
type myType = { ["myKeys"]?: Array<string> }
let data: myType;
data = {};
data["myKeys"] = ["index0"];

console.log(data?.["myKeys"]?.indexOf("index0")) // 0 

if (data?.["myKeys"]?.indexOf("index0") ?? -1 === -1) { // returns false
} else {
    console.log("returns false");
}

data["myKeys"].push("index1")
console.log(data?.["myKeys"]?.indexOf("index1")) // 1

if (data?.["myKeys"]?.indexOf("index1") ?? -1 === -1) { // returns true - why?
    console.log("Why is it true"); 
}
```

Why does the `??` operator behave differently when the index of `index1` is `1` while the index of `index0` is `0`. Both should return false since it's `!== -1`

Playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAtiAq5oF4oG8oG0BEcDSEIAztgLoD8AXFAIIBOdAhiADxHB0CWAdgOYB8UAL4AoADYRgUACaNgjanESQA3CNnyoqNELUbGOfIRKktWbD2kQAHgAYyakQGMA9tyIuJAOjEveACn1yL0MQAmIyYMsbAHkAM38Lbis7bABKNJERTjioQLlGYNDwkyjk2ISklPs0qHJyKABaAEYtZFQW2rQRISgIMSJobqgRqFd3TwgfP0S6SQBXOncoOMYBiHS1UXUC4uMyLzB5ogALROjrZvTnNw9vXwCgkNww-YovC-jz8sv0zOzcvl5EUXiVIh8fl8qjYrrV6k1Wu0Os0uiJRmNbpNpgFsAB1E4gKCcIhEqQceYbNJbIA)

Comment: Operator predecendence?

Comment: What are the `?` on properties (`data?.["myKeys"]?`) for or what do they mean, thanks.

Comment: @lulliezy how about clicking on the first link in the question? :)

Comment: @JonasWilms I know about the **Nullish Coalescing**, I read about that, does this follow under the same?? Because I didn't see it in the **Nullish Coalescing** section

Comment: @lulliezy oh, my bad, that's called *optional chaining* (scroll up)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a precedence issue. Your code is being evaluated as:

```
if (data?.["myKeys"]?.indexOf("index1") ?? (-1 === -1)) {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−^
    console.log("Why is it true");
}
```

but your intention is:

```
if ((data?.["myKeys"]?.indexOf("index1") ?? -1) === -1) {
// −^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
    console.log("Why is it true");
}
```

Oddly, I don't see precedence discussed in [the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing) though it is mentioned in [the draft spec](https://tc39.es/proposal-nullish-coalescing/) as [Jonas mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877149/157247), and it does come up in [the issues](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+precedence).

As you can see, this is consistent with the precedence of `||`, which is its very, very near relative:

```js
const a = 2;
const b = -1;
console.log(`${a} || ${b} === ${b}:   ${a || b === b}`);
console.log(`(${a} || ${b}) === ${b}: ${(a || b) === b}`);
console.log(`${a} || (${b} === ${b}): ${a || (b === b)}`);
```

According to the draft spec, `??` has lower precedence than `||` (presumably *just* lower). (To avoid confusion, it's also not allowed in an `&&` or `||` expression.)

Comment: Yes! On my way to grab more coffee I thought about operator precedence as well. Thank you

Comment: @MuratKaragöz - Surprised me, too. I need to get mano-a-mano with the draft spec. This is Stage 3 so it's at an advanced stage...

Comment: @t.j. As it is seen as "a replacement for `||`" in most cases, it makes sense to have the same predecendence.

Comment: @JonasWilms - Yes indeed. Well, or just lower, but it doesn't really matter that it's lower if it can't be directly in the same expression as `||` (or `&&`) as the current draft spec says... :-)

Answer (score 3):

To quote from the [draft](https://tc39.es/proposal-nullish-coalescing/):

> ?? has lower precedence than ||

Or in other words, your code behaves roughly like:

```
  data?.["myKeys"]?.indexOf("index0") || -1 === -1
```

And that'll be treated as:

```
 (data?.["myKeys"]?.indexOf("index0")) || (-1 === -1)
```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thank you